# C# while loop overwriting scoped variable with each iteration

Tags: c#, list, while-loop, scope, overwrite

I have 2 lists, `allCharges` and `selectedCharges`, where each item in `selectedCharges` is contained in `allCharges`.

I want to create a third list (called `charges`) that is a copy of all charges, but with a boolean property of "Selected" for each item set to true if the charge is in the list of selected charges.

This is fine if I am only doing this once; however, I am trying to perform the same operation five times, rewriting "charges" each time while saving "charges" to my "typeSettingsList".

```
IList<TypeSettings> typeSettingsList = new List<TypeSettings>();

var typeId = 1;
while (typeId < 6)
{
    var links = _linkChargeTypeRepo.Query().Where(l => l.TypeId == typeId);
    var allCharges = _chargeRepo.GetAll().ToList();

    var selectedCharges = links.Select(l => l.ChargeType).ToList();
    selectedCharges.ForEach(c => c.Selected = true);

    var nonSelectedCharges = allCharges.Except(selectedCharges).ToList();
    nonSelectedCharges.ForEach(c => c.Selected = false);

    var charges = nonSelectedCharges.Concat(selectedCharges).ToList();

    var settingsWithType = new TypeSettings
    {
        Type = _typeRepo.Get(typeId),
        Charges = charges
    };

    typeSettingsList.Add(settingsWithType);

    typeId++;
}

return settingsWithType;
```

My problem is that each "Charges" object in my typeSettingsList ends up getting overwritten with the charges object that is created on the last iteration, even though the variable is declared inside the while loop (and should therefore be a new object reference with each iteration).

Is this just an incorrect understanding of how variables inside while loops should work?

How can I make it so my "charges" list isn't overwritten with each iteration?

Comment: selectedCharges is a list variable and TypeSettings (I guess) is not a value type. Each list is new but objects it contains are _reused_

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. My TypeSettings object is an object that contains a Type and a List<ChargeType>. Is there some reason why this should not work?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you do not "materializecharges`: this

```
var charges = nonSelectedCharges.Concat(selectedCharges);
```

is an `IEnumerable<Charge>` with deferred evaluation. By the time you get to evaluate `Charges` from the `typeSettingsList`, the loop is over, so enumerating the `IEnumerable<Charge>` returns the results for the last value of `typeId` (i.e. `typeId = 5`).

Add `ToList()` to fix this problem:

```
var charges = nonSelectedCharges.Concat(selectedCharges).ToList();
```

**Edit:** Another problem is that `links` is using `typeId`, which is modified in the loop. You should define a new variable inside the loop to capture the state of `typeId` during the specific iteration, like this:

```
var typeId = 1;
while (typeId < 6)
{
    var tmpTypeId = typeId;
    var links = _linkChargeTypeRepo.Query().Where(l => l.TypeId == tmpTypeId);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oops, I copy and pasted my code slightly incorrectly. I had the ToList() on there to begin with. I added it now and am getting the same result.

Comment: @MitchVz That is strange. I would expect `Type` to be off, because `typeId` is modified in the loop (assuming that there is some deferred execution there, which may or may not be true). But everything else there uses `ToList()`, so it should simply work. If you are certain that you are running your latest code there, try adding some debug output in the loop to log the key statistics of the charges that you get, perhaps even the lists themselves, and see if the issue occurs at the stage of collecting the charges in the loop.

Comment: Yeah, the `Type` is just about the only thing that is working :)
The object that is returned has five different types, but the same `Charges` list for each type